# How can I reference the Form Ext Object through a listener?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

```
     Mag.NewLightboxForm = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
             initComponent: function () {
                 this.items = [{
                         fieldLabel: 'Select Image',
                         name: 'img',
                         //xtype: 'magcombo',
                         xtype: 'button',
                         id: 'selectlightboximage',
                         store: mageditcontentcombostore,
                         //hiddenName: 'type',
                         listeners: {
                                'render': function() { window.ele = this; }
                         }]
                 }
             });
```

In Ext 3.3, `ele` references the EXT Element. I'm trying to get the reference to `NewLightboxForm` dynamically so I can access `.win` and `.hide()` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the scope in the listener:

```
{
    render: function() {},
    scope: this
}
```

In the function, `this` will now point to the `NewLightBoxForm` instance.